# How could I change ColorTween colors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to change the colors in the ColorTween when I call setState() in Flutter

Here is my animated image

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FingerprintImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  FingerprintImageWidget(
      {Key key, this.width, this.height, this.beginColor, this.endColor})
      : super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  Color beginColor;
  Color endColor;

  @override
  FingerprintImageWidgetState createState() => FingerprintImageWidgetState();
}

class FingerprintImageWidgetState extends State<FingerprintImageWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Color> _colorTween;
  Color beginColor;
  Color endColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    beginColor = widget.beginColor;
    endColor = widget.endColor;
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: beginColor, end: endColor)
        .animate(_animationController);
    changeColors();
    super.initState();
  }


  Future<void> changeColorController;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    disposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool disposed = false;

  Future<void> changeColors() async {
    while (!disposed) {
      if (disposed) return;
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1300), () {
        if (_animationController.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _animationController.reverse();
        } else {
          _animationController.forward();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _colorTween,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => AppImage(
              IMAGE_FINGERPRINT,
              width: widget.width,
              height: widget.height,
              color: _colorTween.value,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by separating the animation object of the color tween object

```
  void redraw(Color beginColor, Color endColor) {
    setState(() {
      _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: beginColor, end: endColor);

      _colorTweenAnimation = _colorTween.animate(_animationController);
    });
  }
```

Full class:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FingerprintImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  FingerprintImageWidget(
      {Key key, this.width, this.height, this.beginColor, this.endColor})
      : super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  Color beginColor;
  Color endColor;

  @override
  FingerprintImageWidgetState createState() => FingerprintImageWidgetState();
}

class FingerprintImageWidgetState extends State<FingerprintImageWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  ColorTween _colorTween;
  Animation<Color> _colorTweenAnimation;
  Color beginColor;
  Color endColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    beginColor = widget.beginColor;
    endColor = widget.endColor;
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: beginColor, end: endColor);
    _colorTweenAnimation = _colorTween.animate(_animationController);
    changeColors();
    super.initState();
  }

  void redraw(Color beginColor, Color endColor) {
    setState(() {
      _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: beginColor, end: endColor);

      _colorTweenAnimation = _colorTween.animate(_animationController);
    });
  }

  Future<void> changeColorController;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    disposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool disposed = false;

  Future<void> changeColors() async {
    while (!disposed) {
      if (disposed) return;
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1300), () {

        if (_animationController.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _animationController.reverse();
        } else {
          _animationController.forward();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _colorTweenAnimation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => AppImage(
              IMAGE_FINGERPRINT,
              width: widget.width,
              height: widget.height,
              color: _colorTweenAnimation.value,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ));
  }
}
```

Then I used a global key so I can call redraw

```
  final GlobalKey<FingerprintImageWidgetState> _fingerprintImageKey =
      GlobalKey();
    FingerprintImageWidget(
                key: _fingerprintImageKey,
                width: 70,
                height: 100,
                beginColor: beginFingerColor,
                endColor: endFingerColor,
              ),
      _fingerprintImageKey.currentState.redraw(beginFingerColor,endFingerColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

In some case, if you want to flick the color multiple times as I want to achieve, you can use `TweenSequence`.

1. Add mixin into stateful state class `class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`.
2. Add local variables and initialize them in `initState`.

```dart
late AnimationController _controller; 
Animation<Color?>? _animation; // Use `Animation` instead of `Animatable`

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 6),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation = TweenSequence<Color?>(
      [
        TweenSequenceItem<Color?>(
          weight: 1,
          tween: ColorTween(
            begin: Colors.blue,
            end: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem<Color?>(
          weight: 1,
          tween: ColorTween(
            begin: Colors.white,
            end: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem(
          weight: 1,
          tween: ColorTween(
            begin: Colors.red,
            end: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ).animate(_controller); // add .animate()
  }
```

3. Using `AnimationBuilder` to build the animation.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _controller,
    builder: (_, child) {
      return Container(
        color: _animation?.value,
        child: ...,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

4. Play the animation by `_controller.forward();`

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = .....;
    _animation = .....;
    _controller.forward(); // here or somewhere
  }
```

5. Dispose the animation controller

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```