# How to make ColorTween animation with multiple colors in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I built this custom card (from UNO game) which looks something like
[image: UNO 4+ game card]

I have used a ColorTween to change the boxshadow property of a container over 1 second, with the following code

```
class SpecialUnoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _value;
  SpecialUnoCard(this._value);

  @override
  _SpecialUnoCardState createState() => _SpecialUnoCardState();
}

class _SpecialUnoCardState extends State<SpecialUnoCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation _animation;
  int index = 0;

  final _listOfTweens = [
    ColorTween(begin: red, end: blue),
    ColorTween(begin: red, end: green),
    ColorTween(begin: red, end: orange),
    ColorTween(begin: blue, end: red),
    ColorTween(begin: blue, end: green),
    ColorTween(begin: blue, end: orange),
    ColorTween(begin: green, end: red),
    ColorTween(begin: green, end: blue),
    ColorTween(begin: green, end: orange),
    ColorTween(begin: orange, end: red),
    ColorTween(begin: orange, end: green),
    ColorTween(begin: orange, end: blue),
  ];

  ColorTween tween() =>
      _listOfTweens[Random().nextInt(_listOfTweens.length - 1)];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    _animation = tween()
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic))
        .animate(_controller);

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _controller.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        _controller.forward();
      }
    });

    _controller.forward();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: _cardMarginVer, horizontal: _cardMarginHor),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_cardCornerRadii),
        border: Border.all(
            color: _animation.value, width: 4, style: BorderStyle.solid),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: _animation.value, spreadRadius: 12, blurRadius: 25)
        ],
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: _cardHeight,
        width: _cardWidth,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: (widget._value == plus4)
            ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/plus4.svg')
            : SvgPicture.asset('assets/wild.svg'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, is there a way to animate or shuffle the colors between a bunch of values ? I want some functionality that relates to the following pseudo code

```
ColorTween(values: <Color>[Colors.orange , Colors.red , Colors.blue , ........]
```

You could say that I want to chain colors together

I have tried looking up the following post, but did not find what I needed.
[How could I change ColorTween colors in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545973/how-could-i-change-colortween-colors-in-flutter)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [RainbowColor](https://pub.dev/packages/rainbow_color) which allows interpolation/tweening among several colors. It provides a multi-color variant of ColorTween exactly as you describe:

```
RainbowColorTween([Colors.orange, Colors.red, Colors.blue])
```

It can also be used outside of tween context to interpolate colors across a spectrum, e.g.

```
var rb = Rainbow(spectrum: [Colors.orange, Colors.red, Colors.blue]);
Color warmColor = rb[0.25];
Color coldColor = rb[0.83];
```

Btw, good timing. I released RainbowColor just yesterday, and I honestly had no idea you asked this question a few days ago when I made it.

Comment: Your solution works exactly how I wanted. I am getting 100% desired result. Thanks a lot for your code and time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the AnimatedContainer at https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container. It's an easier way to handle animations and I think it has exactly what you're looking for. The test code on the page will let you test it immediately. Just put your decoration and integrate the random values a bit to see the magic. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to create your own tween for multiple colors.

1. Write a class to extend `Tween<Color>`
2. Override `transform` and `lerp`
3. For lerp, find the indices of the two colors that should be lerped for the given animation clock `t`.
4. Calculate where your final color should lie between the two colors.
5. Call `Color.lerp()`

Here's an example:

```
class MultiColorTween extends Tween<Color> {
  MultiColorTween(this.spectrum);
  final List<Color> spectrum;

  @override
  Color transform(double t) {
    if (t == 0.0) {
      return spectrum[0];
    }
    if (t == 1.0) {
      return spectrum[spectrum.length - 1];
    }
    return lerp(t);
  }

  @override
  Color lerp(double t) {
    assert(t <= 1.0);
    assert(t >= 0.0);
    // Find where in our spectrum does `t` lie at
    var index = t * (spectrum.length - 1);

    // Floor is our start color, Ceil is our end color
    var colorIndex1 = index.floor();
    var colorIndex2 = colorIndex1 + 1;

    // Calculate where between these two colors, our color lies at. i.e. new `t` between the two colors
    var tweenOffset = index - colorIndex1;

    // Return the lerped color, or return the first color
    return Color.lerp(
            spectrum[colorIndex1], spectrum[colorIndex2], tweenOffset) ??
        spectrum[colorIndex1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedBackground extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedBackground({super.key});

  @override
  _AnimatedBackgroundState createState() => _AnimatedBackgroundState();
}

class _AnimatedBackgroundState extends State<AnimatedBackground> {
  late Timer _timer;
  final List<Color> _colors = [
    const Color(0xFFFF0000), // Red
    const Color(0xFFFF7F00), // Orange
    const Color(0xFFFFFF00), // Yellow
    const Color(0xFF00FF00), // Green
    const Color(0xFF0000FF), // Blue
    const Color(0xFF4B0082), // Indigo
    const Color(0xFF9400D3), // Violet
  ];
  double _animationValue = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 40), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        _animationValue = (sin(timer.tick / 60) + 1) /
            2; // Adjust the factor for the speed and smoothness
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            gradient: SweepGradient(
              startAngle: 0.0,
              endAngle: 2 * pi,
              colors: [
                _interpolateColor(_animationValue),
                _interpolateColor((_animationValue + 0.1) % 1.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color _interpolateColor(double t) {
    final index1 = (t * (_colors.length - 1)).floor();
    final index2 = (index1 + 1) % _colors.length;
    final color1 = _colors[index1];
    final color2 = _colors[index2];
    final factor = t * (_colors.length - 1) - index1;
    return Color.lerp(color1, color2, factor)!;
  }
}
```